# Spring Security Login - don't see change on MySql data table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

I'm implementing login with spring security and JWT.
After table Account (which used for login credentials), change for e.g. password manual on MySql workbranch, `JPA` doesn't see change, i still got old password on User details.

-UserDetails class:

```
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Object[] account =  userDao.findByUserName(username);
        boolean enabled = true;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;
        User user = new User((String) account[0], (String) account[1], enabled, accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, getAuthorities((String) account[2]));
        System.out.println(user);
        return user;
    }



public Object[] findByUserName(String username) {
        try {

            entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
            String query = "SELECT a.username, a.password, a.role FROM Account a WHERE a.isConfirmed = 1 AND a.username = :username";
            TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query, Object[].class);

            typedQuery.setParameter("username", username);
            Object[] result = typedQuery.getResultList().get(0);
            entityManager.clear();
            entityManager.close();

            System.out.println(result[1]);
            return result;

        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("persist failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you using the JPA cache ?

Comment: I disabled on persistance.xml file and also i put annotation @Cacheable(false) on entity table.

Comment: when you restart the application do you get the old or the new password?

Comment: Than i got new password.

Comment: then i assume 90% that is a problem of cache ;)

Comment: can you share how you get the User details?

Comment: Thank you, i will check did i disabled cache, but i think i do everything for disabled cache.

Comment: so `System.out.println(result[1]);` gives you the old password right?

Comment: please use `entityManager.clear();` before `getResultList`

Comment: Yes, first i got 'correct password', and when updated i still got the same password.

Comment: i put entityManager.clear() above, but still same issue. @YCF_L

Comment: mmm, i'm not sure @NidalSalkic but i think you make it a little complected when you get information what jpa version you are using?

Comment: Version of JPA is 2.1  @YCF_L

Comment: usuly when i want to not use the cache i just use `@Cacheable(false)` and every thing work fine, i don't use `entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();` or `entityManager.clear();
            entityManager.close();` in my code at all try without them please

Comment: try with this methods please https://ideone.com/o0q2h6

Comment: @YCF_L I'm solved isuess, problem was been on cache and on shared entityManager. Thank you for help.